# GeoExplorer dependencies are missing after git clone

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

When I set up GeoExplorer in development mode today I had to manually clone the external js libs that are referenced in git (buildkit, stick, geoext, gxp, openlayers, printpreview, proj4js).

They were not included after running "git clone git://github.com/opengeo/suite.git", which prevented me from building GeoExplorer with maven. After adding them manually everything works. What am I missing in my git/maven configuration to skip this step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run

```
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```

on the root of the Suite repository.

Comment: Thanks for your reliable support and the great software!